# Cannot Find Symbol on Import Project line because of Dependency Conflict in Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, applitools

I am working on Visual Testing using Applitools eyes which is integrated within my Selenium Framework. Selenium Jar File that I am using currently is 2.52 and the Applitools jar file version that I am using is eyes-selenium-java 2.56. This internally uses Selenium java version 3.5.3 for compilation. So I am not sure if this dependency version conflict is causing a cannot find symbol error on "Actions", Browser Type" and "Desired Capabilities" class even though I have imported the correct classes.

Unfortunately I cant upgrade my selenium version to 3.5. Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dependency:list`, you can see the exact versions of all artifacts on your classpath. Check whether the classes you desire can be found in the artifacts you got.

If `eyes-selenium-java:2.56` uses a new selenium version which you cannot use, look for an older version of `eyes-selenium-java` that is compatible with your version of selenium.